# How to use an array values inside a Mysql query with 'IN' operator?

Tags: php, mysql

`$_POST['domain']` is the result of some form's CHECKBOX with 3 or more values of domain (C,C++,Java,etc.), whose value is now saved in an array `'$Domain'`. Now, I need to select the tuples from my table which are in the same domain as selected by the user in the CHECKBOX.

I tried using FOR loop, but it gave me a T_FOR unexception
   error or something. Now I'm trying it with implode function, its not
   giving any query error but not showing any result from the query
   either!  The PROBLEM is within the IN operator of the query. How
   can I solve it?

```
if(isset($_POST['domain']))
    {
        $Domain = $_POST['domain'];
        $search=$_POST['search'];

        $N = count($Domain);

        echo("<p>You selected $N domain(s):<br/><br/> ");
        for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
        {
            echo($Domain[$i] . "<br/> ");
        }
        echo("</p>");

        $dom_str="'".implode("', '",$Domain)."'";

    $query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND 
            lo_domain IN ( ".$dom_str." ) ";

    $result =mysql_query($query)
    or die('query failed.'.mysql_error());

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            echo  "<a href=\" ".$row['lo_url']." \" target=\"_blank\" \">"  .   $row['lo_name']  .   "</a> <br/> ";     
            echo $row['lo_desc']."<br/><br/>";      
        }
     }
     else
     echo "<p>You didn't select any Domain.</p><br/>";
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: $query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND lo_domain IN ( 'Data Structures', 'General' ) ";                                          is working just fine , so where is the problem ?

Comment: Read my comment well. This has nothing to do with your query, but with the functions you're using.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha So do I have to rewrite the whole code with all the new functions starting from mysql_connect or only the few functions that are troubling the code .

Comment: I'm not saying "rewrite old code" I'm saying "don't use it in new code". Please read the links on the comment to better understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: yeah i am readinf that , i was asking if i have to use any function like '$stmt = $db->prepare()' , do i have to change mysql_connect to '$db = new PDO()' or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to u all for helping me out. I've figured the correct code with all your help.
Query:-

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND lo_domain IN ( '" . implode("','", array_map('trim', $Domain)) ."' ); ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  $dom_str=!empty($Domain)?implode(",",$Domain):'default value';

$query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND 
        lo_domain IN ($dom_str)";
```

Comment: i think problem is the quotes (''). result should be 'c','c++' but its coming c, c++. Will this effect the query ?

Comment: if you want to use 'c','c++' in your query then use "'".implode("', '",$Domain)."'" instead of implode(",",$Domain),or do you mean result from query(i.r value of $row['lo_domain'])

Comment: yeah u r right, i did that too nut its still not working . BUT      $query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND lo_domain IN ( 'Data Structures', 'General' ) ";    is working just fine , so where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = implode (',',$Domain);  
$query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND 
        lo_domain IN ( ".$dom." ) ";
```

Comment: query failed.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Structures , General )' at line 1

Comment: actually join is replaced by implode in new version

Comment: i think problem is the quotes (''). result should be 'c','c++' but its coming c, c++. Will this effect the query ? But even after that quer error is removed but screen is blank.

Comment: $query ="SELECT * FROM learner_object WHERE(lo_tag1='$search' || lo_tag2='$search' || lo_tag3='$search') AND lo_domain IN ( 'Data Structures', 'General' ) ";    is working just fine , so where is the problem ?

Comment: $in_condition = implode(', ', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $Domain));

Comment: just echo($dom_str) and paste it here

Comment: @softsdev same error ...result of echo $in_condition : Data Structures , General.